# Disable Text is not working on webpage for IE and Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have written CSS to disable the selection of numbers (CSS class "table_border") in the webpage. It is working as expected for Chrome and Firefox. However, I am still able to select the numbers when we drag from top in Edge and IE browsers. Please find the below snippet for more details.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.tableText>.table_head th {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

.tableText {
  background: #5d5d5d;
  padding: 3px;
}

.table_border {
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}

.table-striped>tbody>.row_border:nth-child(even)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>.row_border:nth-child(odd)>td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableText">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table_head">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Python</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class="row_border">
        <td class="table_border">1</td>
        <td>try:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">
        <td class="table_border">2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x= 1/0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">
        <td class="table_border">3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">
        <td class="table_border">4</td>
        <td>except ZeroDivisionError:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">
        <td class="table_border">5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;print ("You can't divide by zero, you're silly.")</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try `pointer-event:none`:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: IE suport it see here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: nope, it is not working

Comment: try to copy the code from here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: In IE11 its not selecting, which version you are using?

Comment: if you use IE under 10 there is not support for this

Comment: I am using IE11 only @charankumar

Comment: @charankumar  Works VISUALLY in EDGE for me - starting at Python it only selects code, but it copies all

Comment: @Shas maybe something override this declaretion: see in F12 and try to set `!important`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, in EDGE it copies all the output displayed.

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes I tried putting !important also and there is no code overrides the declaration

Comment: Is there is any other option either using css or javascript ?

Comment: Try `onselectstart="return false"` see here:https://jsfiddle.net/gem87xmq/

Comment: @לבנימלכה the onselectstart event should be used along with the class "table_border" right ?

Comment: yes see here:https://jsfiddle.net/gem87xmq/21/

Comment: the all above codes will work when we select only table_border, but if we select from parent automatically table_border also will select

Comment: Hooo I see I will update a new one...

Comment: @לבנימלכה it looks fine visually while selecting the code, however if you try to copy and paste, it selects all the code including numbers

Comment: @charankumar  see my answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nice trick [`psuedo element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

`psuedo element` is never `selectable` so you can create `:before` to `tr td:first-child` and with `aria-label=""` set the value you want

See here:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
.tableText>.table_head th {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  margin:0;
}
.tableText {
  background: #5d5d5d;
  padding: 5px;
}
tr td:first-child:before {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  border-right: 5px solid #5d5d5d;
  padding: 8px;
}
.table-striped>tbody>.row_border:nth-child(even)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>.row_border:nth-child(odd)>td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableText">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table_head">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Python</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class="row_border">            
        <td aria-label="1">try:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">           
        <td aria-label="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x= 1/0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">            
        <td aria-label="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">           
        <td aria-label="4">except ZeroDivisionError:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row_border">            
        <td aria-label="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;print ("You can't divide by zero, you're silly.")</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)

Comment: Thanks, @ לבנימלכה. It is now selecting numbers also in EDGE and IE 11, however, in EDGE when we try to copy and paste, I am able to paste only python code not numbers.

Comment: In IE 11 I am still facing the same issue, copies all the code including numbers

Comment: how can you cpy without select??

Comment: and in IE it select the index also?

Comment: @ לבנימלכה yes, It is selecting numbers also